# How do we retain polymorphism after serializing an object to Json

Tags: c#, json, oop, serialization, polymorphism

We have a complex issue in our system regarding retaining polymorphism after we have saved a config file to the database.

We have simplified the problem for the sake of this question. See code below.

Here is the code:

```
class Wheel
{
    public virtual string GetWidth()
    {
        return "Normal";
    }
}

class SmallWheel : Wheel
{
    public override string GetWidth()
    {
        return "Small";
    }
}

class BigWheel : Wheel
{
    public override string GetWidth()
    {
        return "Big";
    }
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //Build list of wheels
    var wheels = new List<Wheel>()
    {
        new Wheel(),
        new SmallWheel(),
        new BigWheel(),
    };

    //We print wheels to check it works
    foreach (var x in wheels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetWidth());
    }

    //Save the list to the db as a string
    var file = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wheels);

    //We just use file instead of db for simplictiydf

    //Later we read the config file from the DB
    var wheelsFromDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wheel>>(file);

    //We now want to print out our wheels.
    Console.WriteLine("Printing WHeels from Db");
    foreach (var x in wheelsFromDb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetWidth());
    }
}
```

Results when I run it:

```
Normal
Small
Big

Printing WHeels from Db
Normal
Normal
Normal
```

Now as you can see we are losing what type the wheel is after de-serialisation.

How can we go about solving this issue?

In essence, we need to store a config file with multiple children classes each with overrides functions.  I realise that when Json deserializes the raw string it has no context of what type the class was before.  Is there a way we can store that context or use a different library or database?

Comment: Note that the objects also have properties but for the example we are only using virtual functions since this is the way we get computed values from our config objects

Comment: Q: How do I distinguish different object types in my serialized Json file?  A: Add a "type" field to your Json.  EXAMPLE: "Wheel.json": `{ "type":"small", "width":42}`

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code for a list of derived classes. You can use a base class instead of an interface as well

```
IAnimal[] animals = new IAnimal[] {
                    new Cat{CatName="Tom"},
                    new Dog{DogName="Scoopy"},
                    new Rabbit{RabitName="Honey"}
    };

    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(animals, jsonSerializerSettings);
    

    List<IAnimal> animalsBack = ((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)).Select(o => (IAnimal)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(o.ToString(), Type.GetType((string)o["$type"]))).ToList();
```

classes

```
public interface IAnimal
{
}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{
}
    
public class Cat : IAnimal { public string CatName { get; set; } }
public class Dog : IAnimal { public string DogName { get; set; } }
public class Rabbit : IAnimal { public string RabitName { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Hi, this will work thanks, but it does not solve our use case, we need to be able to have Function Polymorphism, since we need to have overridden functions that modify values based on lots of properties in our configs, we can not just use Class properties

Comment: @TiaanLeGrange You have to post all details. I can not guess what are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert` creates property `$type` under the hood when `TypeNameHandling.All` is used.

So we can give a clue to compiler about what type actually is by creating `Size` property in classes:

```
public class Wheel
{
    public virtual string Size { get;  set; } = WheelSize.NORMAL;

    public virtual string GetWidth() => Size;
    
}

public class SmallWheel : Wheel
{
    public override string Size { get; set; } = WheelSize.SMALL;
}

public class BigWheel : Wheel
{
    override public string Size { get; set; } = WheelSize.BIG;
}
```

This is a class which contains size of wheels:

```
public class WheelSize
{
    public static string SMALL = "small";
    public static string NORMAL = "normal";
    public static string BIG = "big";
}
```

So far, so good. But how we can deserialize json based on size wheel? We can write custom deserializer:

```
internal class WheelJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public WheelJsonConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Wheel> wheels = new List<Wheel>();
        WheelToSize wheelToSize = new WheelToSize();

        JArray jArray = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (JToken token in jArray)
        {
            string wheelSize = token["size"].ToString();
            Wheel wheel =  wheelToSize.WheelBySize[wheelSize];
            wheels.Add(wheel);
        }

        return wheels;
    }


    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {   
        if (objectType.IsGenericType 
            && IsGenericTypeArgumentTheSame(objectType))            
            return true;
        
        return false;
    }

    private bool IsGenericTypeArgumentTheSame(Type objectType) => 
        objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0] == _types[0];

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)t;
            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class to create json in lower case:

```
public class LowercaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName.ToLower();
    }
}
```

This is a factory which creates an object based on size:

```
public class WheelToSize
{
    public Dictionary<string, Wheel> WheelBySize { get; private set; } = new()
    {
        { WheelSize.NORMAL, new Wheel() },
        { WheelSize.BIG, new BigWheel() },
        { WheelSize.SMALL, new SmallWheel() }
    };
}
```

And then you can run code like this:

```
List<Wheel> wheels = new List<Wheel>()
{
    new Wheel(),
    new SmallWheel(),
    new BigWheel(),
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver();
var file = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wheels, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var wheelsFromDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wheel>>(file, 
    new WheelJsonConverter(typeof(Wheel)));

//We now want to print out our wheels.
Console.WriteLine("Printing WHeels from Db");
foreach (var x in wheelsFromDb)
    Console.WriteLine(x.GetWidth());
```